# Using enterprise geodatabase with ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, esri-geodatabase

I need to create an online map using ArcGIS Online.  The data is stored in an enterprise geodatabase.

Can I add the data to a map directly from the geodatabase?

If not, what's the best way to add it?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up an ArcMap Document containing those feature class(es) and publish it online, but keep in mind that ArcGIS Online uses the data stored on its servers, once you publish layers, the data is disconnected from your enterprise geodatabase. If you data does not need to be updated in real-time in your enterprise gdb, this option may be good, but if your project requires that edits made in either your enterprise gdb / online service be synchronized in real-time, you need ArcGIS Server to do this.